# Pointers don't point to the right place in a vector of pointers to a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, new-operator

I have two classes: `spot` and `frame`.

`spot` holds data about a spot detected by some image processor: it has only an `id` (int) which is unique, and `x`,`y`-coordinates (both double). I store all the spots in a vector I call `spots`.

`frame` holds, among other things, a vector of pointers to all the spots that belong to it:

```
class frame
{
    int num ;
    vector <spot *> spots_list ;
    // other members and functions
}
```

I read the data from a file:

```
while (//goes through a lot of rows)
    {
        spot* S = new spot (ID, X, Y) ;
        spots.push_back (*S)  ;
        frames[i].spot_list.push_back (&spots.back()) ;
        delete S ;
    }
```

so essentially, I'm creating a new instance `S`, and then I add its data to vector `spots`, and add a pointer to its address to frame's `spot_list`.
(at least, this is what I want to do)

When I try to print all the points in a frame, some of them hold garbage data: e.g. id=423784237, id=-9431101 - and the rest have valid data.

But, when I check it against the vector `spots` directly, it's not pointing to the right place.
For example, **id=37** is in cell **0x20f8288** in the frame's `spot_list`, but at **0x210d080** in the vector `spots`.

Since there's random garbage data and the addresses are not the same, I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this correctly - but I don't understand what I should do differently. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why do you first allocate on the heap, then make a copy and store it, then delete the original?

Comment: You take the address of the vector's back element `&spots.back()` but that address **changes** if the vector needs to reallocate because you added more elements. As soon as you call `push_back` all the pointers you took to its elements are *invalidated*.

Comment: If you want `spots` to have stable addresses for its elements when adding to its ends then you can use `std::deque` instead.

Comment: How is this working `spots.push_back (*S)  ;` when `vector <spot *> spots_list ;` is the vector declaration?

Comment: And why are you using `new` at all? You store the element **by value** and then delete it!! Just create it like `spot S(ID, X, Y); spots.push_back(S);` forget about `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @Galik : I took a small break from work, drank some coffee, and re-read what I wrote. Indeed there were several weird things I did there, and I changed them as you advised. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

Also, I learned two new things today: vector isn't as forgetting as I thought, and I got to use deque, which is great.
(I'm not a CS student but a physicist, although that shouldn't really be an excuse!)

Answer (score 0):

```
spots.push_back(*S);
```

This call will sometimes need to reallocate the storage inside `spots`; when that happens, any previously-stored addresses become invalid, so the entries in the `spots_list` become bogus.

If you know how large the vector will be, you can either pre-allocate the internals of `spots` with `spots.reserve(size)`; otherwise, you can store indices into the vector instead of pointers.